# How do you manage a team email account?

Tags: email, process

How do you manage a (tech support) team email account? Do you have any recommended resources for managing accounts accessed by multiple people?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would go with Lucas's suggestion below (also see my comment). Can you tell us more about this account (does it have to exist to keep a copy of messages, or just as a central place to send messages to, or something else?)

Comment: How is this a sysadmin problem?  How an organization manages a shared mailbox really is about people and has nothing to do with technology. If you think having a shared mailbox, is required, then there really isn't much we can to do help you.  We generally focus on answering the practical technical problems here.

Comment: The account needs to be maintained for queries, escalation, follow up etc. It's not used for reporting incidents, so a ticketing system (whilst a good suggestion) isn't really what's required. It needs to be a team account for various reasons, and so I am looking for resources on the management of that (and not finding any).

Comment: @zordache - This isn't a sysadmin problem, and my understanding is that this is not a pure sysadmin forum ('Q&A for system administrators and desktop support professionals'). It's a tech support process query and I did meta the best place to post this question before posting.

Answer (score 13):

I recommend not making it one account but a mailinglist. You can also let the tech support email point to a ticketing system (e.g. [Request Tracker](http://cloud101.eu/blog/2012/03/01/request-tracker-4-what-is-it-how-to-install-it-on-debian-squeeze/)), so you can make annotations to the request and easily retrieve the history of the ticket.

One account with one password is not really good practice, actually a mailinglist isn't either.

Get yourself a ticketing system.

Comment: +1 for a ticketing system

Comment: Thanks - but if the email account still needs to exist are there any management strategies?

Comment: +1 for ticketing systems -- It depends on why the "email account [...] needs to exist": If it's just a central place for customers to send email to request support you set it up so messages to that account go right into a ticketing system like Request Tracker and double your win: Customers have one place to email, and your users have a system to help them manage workflow.

Comment: This is what I do as well.  Request Tracker will take incoming emails to support@xyz.com and create a ticket for it with the contents of the email and attachments.  All the staff can log in to RT to view and comment on the ticket, or take ownership of it.  Saves us from duplicating work and lets us know who is working on what.

Comment: -1 because it's not answer on asked question. And irrelevant to it

Comment: Actually I did answer his question, it's how to manage a team mail account. So it means a mailinglist would be the easiest, unless of course you want to share passwords. A ticketing system is by far the best for his purpose since it's more flexible to maintain and have grip on the problem. Also, I don't see you coming up with a better solution...

Comment: @LazyBadger "Just because you didn't hear what you wanted does not mean I did not answer your question." -- Axioms of System Administration. :-)

Comment: I'd prefer all the "shared mailboxes" in our departments to be replaced with ticket systems, really.